# Mapping an RAList Range in Racket returns the empty list

Tags: racket

I'm using ralists and mapping a range onto the random-number function, but my result is the empty list.

```
#lang racket
(require data/ralist)
(map (lambda (_) (random 100))
     (range 10))
```

returns '(), whereas it should return 10 random numbers, right?

After getting rid of the ralist require, it works:

```
#lang racket
(map (lambda (_) (random 100))
     (range 10))
```

returns:

> (88 5 78 12 31 23 45 17 64 96)

Just doing the range by itself works with and without the require:

```
#lang racket
(range 10)
```

returns:

> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

```
#lang racket
(require data/ralist)
(range 10)
```

also returns:

> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9).

So I'm not sure what about ralist is causing it or map to misbehave above.

PS I know build-list is probably the better way to build such a list, but I'm interested in why this isn't working.

Comment: What version of Racket are you using? I've got version 6.01 and data/ralist doesn't seem to be included. Is this a package you downloaded from somewhere? If so, seeing the source and/or documentation of that might help.

Comment: 6.1, sorry I should have mentioned RAList is David Van Horn's Purely Functional Random-Access Lists (http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=ralist.plt&owner=dvanhorn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ralist` is included, `map` is redefined as such:

```
;; [X -> y] [RaListof X] -> [RaListof Y]
;; Takes advantage of the fact that map produces a list of equal size.
(define ra:map
  (case-lambda 
    [(f ls)
     (let recr ((ls ls))   
       (match ls
         [(struct kons (s t r))
          (make-kons s (tree-map f t) (recr r))]
         [else ra:empty]))]
    [(f . lss)
     (let recr ((lss lss))
       (cond [(ra:empty? (car lss)) ra:empty]
             [else
              ;; IMPROVE ME: make one pass over lss.
              (make-kons (kons-size (car lss))
                         (tree-map/n f (map kons-tree lss))
                         (recr (map kons-rest lss)))]))]))
```

The contract states that it expects an `RaListof X`. `(list)` is overloaded by this module to create a `RaListof`, which is why if you tried:

```
#lang racket
(require (planet dvanhorn/ralist:3:5))
(map (lambda (_) (random 100))
    (list 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
```

you would get something like:

```
(38 8 62 99 87 24 57 18 28 39)
```

My recommendation: redefine `(range)` to return a `RaListof`.

Here is an example that uses the ALSO redefined `(build-list)`:

```
(define (range n)
  (build-list n (lambda (x) x)))
```

---

EDIT:

I added this function to the main RaList source, [as seen here](https://github.com/dvanhorn/ralist/pull/5).

Comment: @user2741287, I have added the range function to the main RaList source